# How do I use an IF statement on a datetime from Dictionary<string, List<datetime>> in C#

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, if-statement, npoco

The data I am pulling from the database is (string, datetime) and I need to review datetime to see if it equals sysdate today @ 14:00, but i can't figure out how to just look at the datetime field from list.

```
int recordCount;

using (IDatabase db = SystemStatus.GetDatabase(_connectionStrings.stuff))
{
    const string query= @"
        SELECT DISTINCT string, date
        FROM table
        WHERE date > DATE_SUB(SYSDATE(), Interval 30 day) AND
              drop_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), Interval 12 hour) AND 
              status_id = 2;";

    var records = db.Fetch<Dictionary<string, List<DateTime>>>(query);

    recordCount = records.Count;                               
}
```

Comment: NPoco . The query works. The data passes my health check. Everything works, passes value, if return is above 0 it sets status to bad and alerts appropriately. My problem is extracting the dates to set a time parameter. Im looking to seperate records in status 2 before 2 pm vs. Ones after. Ones before that time are fine and i cant figure out how to sort on timestamp in mysql, so im trying to create an if statement but i cant seem to seperate the string from the datetime

Comment: I updated my answer. You do not need an "if" statement, you need a condition to produce a separate list from your dictionary. It's quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

You need a datetime object for your comparison:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime dt = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, 14, 0, 0); // 2 PM today
```

You don't need an "if" statement. You need to use object querying (LINQ)...

```
using System.Linq; 

// get everything past 2 PM today
var after2PMRecords = records.Where(r => r.Value > dt);

// get everything before 2 PM today
var before2PMRecords = records.Where(r => r.Value < dt);
```